# Removing macOS boot-args without booting when firmware password enabled

Tags: macos, startup, macbook-pro

After setting a bad combination of gzalloc boot-args fields, the booting of every kernel i’ve tried fails (usb bootable, recovery, internet recovery, safe, etc...). The firmware password protection disables the boot keys usually used to reset PRAM so there is no trivial way to remove these boot preventing boot-args. How could i reset the firmware pw or the PRAM without going on a trip to the apple store?

I have a 2020 16 inch MBP with latest Big Sur

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! There's a good chance I don't fully understand what's going on here, but you're saying that you can't disable some of the boot flags you set for the NVRAM, correct? If so, this should only affect your ability to boot macOS. Can you try using [rEFInd](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) (or similar program) to do a one-time boot with different boot flags into the Recovery Partition, disable your firmware password, and perform an NVRAM reset (or just use the `nvram` CLU to set them manually?)

Comment: The boot args affect recovery kernel also so i cant make it to recovery mode. Refind and cli utilites are not an option. Also, i have the external boot protection enabled so booting linux is also out.

Comment: Can you try installing rEFInd/Linux to the internal drive using Target Disk Mode?